# Show that: $ \int_{E}{g_\infty(t)d\mu(t)}\leq \lim_{n}{\int_{E}{g_n(t)d\mu(t)}} $

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}$, such that $\{\min\bigl(0,f_n(\cdot)\bigr)\}$ (the negative parts of $f_n$) is uniformly integrable.

Let $\{g_n\}$ be a sequence defined by: for all $n\geq 1$, $g_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f_i}$. So  $\{\min\bigl(0,g_n(\cdot)\bigr)\}$  is also   uniformly integrable.

We suppose that there exists $g_\infty\in\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}$ such that:
$$
g_\infty(t)=\lim_n g_n(t)\qquad\text{a.e.}
$$

Show that:
$$
\int_{E}{g_\infty(t)d\mu(t)}\leq \lim_{n}{\int_{E}{g_n(t)d\mu(t)}}
$$

An idea please.

Comment: What do you mean by "a function is uniformly integrable"? It is not clear to me what the assumptions are. Consider the special case $f_n \equiv -1$. Then the sequence $(g_n)$ isn't uniformly integrable.

Comment: Yes, but then the limit $g_\infty$ is identically $-\infty$, which violates the OP's assumption that $g\in L^1$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement holds with $\liminf$ instead of $\lim$ (nothing in your hypotheses guarantees that there exists $\lim\int g_n d\mu$), and regardless of the fact that $g_n$ was actually defined as a partial sum of the $f_n$'s. But in any case that should serve your purpose.

First, by [Vitali's convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem) applied to the negative part $-[g_n]^-$, your assumption on the a.e. pointwise convergence and the uniform integrability shows that $-[g_n]^-$ converges strongly in $L^1$ to the limit $-[g_\infty]^-$, hence
$$
\lim -\int[g_n]^-d\mu=-\int[g_\infty]^- d\mu.
$$

Apply next [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma) to the positive part and conclude that
$$
\int [g_\infty]^+ d\mu \leq \liminf \int [g_n]^+ d\mu.
$$

Putting both steps together you get
\begin{multline*}
\int g_\infty d\mu=-\int[g_\infty]^-d\mu+\int [g_\infty]^+d\mu\\
\leq \lim -\int[g_n]^-d\mu+ \liminf \int [g_n]^+d\mu
\\
\leq \liminf \left(-\int[g_n]^-d\mu+ \int [g_n]^+d\mu\right)
=\liminf\int g_n d\mu.
\end{multline*}
QED.